# can't understand how to use sim folder in binutils

Tags: binutils

I am porting binutils to a new arch. What is the sim folder for ? and how can I use it ? If I understand correctly, the sim folder suppose to build some kind of simulator for the new arch but I can't find any information about it. Is there more information anywhere ?

Answer (score 2):

The `sim` directory is indeed for simulators.  When you build gdb, you can choose to enable a simulator, if one exists, for the primary target (there's no support for building multiple simulators).  The simulator is then linked into gdb and can be accessed using `target sim`.  There's a section in the manual explaining more about this.

It's certainly possible to write a new sim.  However, if I was doing a port to a new arch, I would instead consider writing a qemu port.  Qemu is faster and useful for more things than the gdb sims.